# Flink: The implementation of the RichSinkFunction is not serializable

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I am trying to sink stream to s3 bucket and implements the `Encoder` interface.

```
case class Info(vecId: Long, bkCode: String, state: String)

class S3Encoder extends Encoder[Info] {

    private val gson = new Gson()

    override def encode(element: Info, stream: OutputStream): Unit = {

      val json = new util.HashMap[String, Any]()

      json.put("vecId", element.vecId)
      json.put("bk", element.bkCode)
      json.put("state", element.state)

//      println(gson.toJson(json))
      stream.write(gson.toJson(json).getBytes("UTF-8"))
      stream.write('\n')

    }
```

And I added the sink to

```
val sink: StreamingFileSink[Info] = StreamingFileSink
            .forRowFormat(new Path(s3_path), new S3Encoder)
            .build()
```

But met the error `non-serializable`, any one can shed light on this?
Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm assuming your `Gson` class isn't serializable

Comment: This looks right! There is no error when I put `gson` inside the `encode` function